# jQuery can't select element in iframe

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I use Visual Composer plugin in WP theme. Parallax scrolling works well on frontend, but when I changing page with VC frontend editor parallax scrolling is not working, and some other jQuery code also.

how can I fix it?

Comment: Is the source of the iframe the same as the parent document?

Comment: no, they are not the same. But the domain is the same

Comment: OK just checking, as that would have given you a whole other issue :)

Comment: jquery code in iframe can't select elements, but when I open this page without iframe it work properly

Comment: If they are on the same domain, you can select the elements, but you need to follow one of the answers below. You have to use the contents() function to get the elements inside of the iframe.

Comment: I don't need to select elements from children page. I just need children page to work properly when I use it in iframe on parent page

Comment: OK is the path to jquery the same? I assume it is. At this point we are going to need to see your code, and understand the structure of the iframe and parent document.

Comment: I use Visual Composer plugin in WP theme. Parallax scrolling works well on frontend, but when I changing page with VC frontend editor parallax scrolling is not working, and some other jQuery code also.

Comment: I think the only way anyone can help you is if you post your code, or share a link to your site.

Answer (score 1):

Assign your frame an id and then in the find element add your element id.

```
$('#iframe_id').contents().find('iframe').contents().find('#element');
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get element within iframe, you have to use "contents()" feature of jquery :

```
$( "#iframe" ).contents().find( "div" ).each(function(){
   // your function goes here
})
```

Comment: no, I don't need to get element within iframe, I want content in iframe work well